# Ошибка в отображении картинки в OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Код:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat test = imread("test_img.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if (!test.data) {
        cout << "Image not found!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    imshow("test", test);

    waitKey(0);
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать просто вывод картинки. Изначально, была проблема в том что в консоль выводилась следующая ошибка (как я понимаю, она обозначает, что картинка пустая)

> Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow,
>   file
>   c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp,
>   line 352

Я добавил условие чтобы программа не вылетала с ошибкой и удостоверился,что проблема в том, что OpenCV видит картинку как пустую.
Условие:

```
if (!test.data) {
    cout << "Image not found!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

И с какой бы фотографией я не пробовал, ничего не меняется и картинка не отображается и либо вызывается ошибка, указанная выше, либо отображается моё сообщение "Image not found!" и программа закрывается.

P.S. Так же удостоверился, что картинка, которую пытаюсь отобразить действительно имеет формат .jpg и находиться в корне программы.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать полный путь к файлу

Comment: @bobtorus, уже пробовал - результат тот же

Comment: 1) Проверьте правильность пути; 2) Проверьте правильность сборки библиотеки (подобные ошибки могут возникать, например, при смешении Debug/Release версий и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуете получить Mat из raw данных. Для этого считайте файл средствами C++, как это сделать обсуждается [тут](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22901/reading-all-bytes-from-a-file). Далее используйте стандартный конструктор Mat для массива байт

```
Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC3, указатель-на-массив-байт);
```

P.S. Убедитесь, что канальность вашего изображения равна трем (png без прозрачностей или jpg) или поменяйте CV_8UC3 на CV_8UC4

Answer (score -1):

Была идентичная проблема,оказалось, что в свойствах проекта следует разделить библиотеки для конфигураций отладки и релиза.

Во вкладке компоновщик->ввод в дополнительных зависимостях путь до opencv...d.lib указывается только для debug конфигурации,а  opencv....lib для release. Я указывал оба файла для всех конфигураций и в моём случае это было причиной ошибки.

Comment: Извините, а как вам этого удалось добится? Спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]